# How to exclude submission values from saving?

Tags: drupal-8, submission, drupal-webform

Is there a way to exclude certain submission values from being saved to the submissions table in Drupal? I would like to send a complete set of all submission values per submission via email, but I would like to exclude personal data like email-addresses and the like from being saved to the table. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: You can use a hook (ie. `hook_form_validate`)  to check what values are being submitted and eventually alter some of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drupal's webform submission exporter service to export submission data and also exclude unwanted columns during export. Something like this:

```
$submission_exporter = \Drupal::service('webform_submission.exporter');
$export_options = $submission_exporter->getDefaultExportOptions();
$export_options['excluded_columns'] = [
        'uuid' => 'uuid',
        'token' => 'token',
        'webform_id' => 'webform_id',
        'completed' => 'completed',
];
$submission_exporter->setWebform($webform);
$submission_exporter->setExporter($export_options);
$submission_exporter->generate();
$temp_file_path = $submission_exporter->getExportFilePath();
```